# generating token from a file by passing command line arguments

Tags: javascript, php, python, hosting, web-hosting

I have a file(python,jar) which generates a token for the command line arguments passed to it, I have tried using PHP exec() function but my 000webhost server doesn't allow to execute the exec call.Python file to execute:

```
python3 generateToken.py --key=rUlaMASgt1Byi4Kp3sKYDeQzo --appID=ApplicationID --userName=user1 --expiresInSecs=10000
```

Java file to execute : 
`java -jar generateToken.jar --key=rUlaMASgt1Byi4Kp3sKYDeQzo --appID=ApplicationID --userName=user1 --expiresInSecs=10000`

is there any other way around to do it in php or javascript.

Comment: Try system(), but if exec is blocked, I almost sure system will be as well...  There is also passthru, same comment applies.

Comment: system, show_source, exec, shell_exec, proc_open, passthru, all are disabled